# How to Create a Radio Button Group with PDFBox 2.0

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to create a Radio Button group using PDFBox 2.0, I am able to create 3 Radio Buttons, but I can't figure out how to group them (PDFBox 1.8, used [PDRadioCollection](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDRadioCollection.html), but 2.0 doesn't.).

How do you create a Radio Button Group with PDFBox 2.0?

Here is my current code:

```
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);
        document.addPage(page);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        PDResources res = new PDResources();
        COSName fontName = res.add(PDTrueTypeFont.load(document, new FileInputStream("C:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf"), StandardEncoding.INSTANCE));
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
        acroForm.setDefaultAppearance('/' + fontName.getName() + " 10 Tf 0 g");

        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        List<String> options = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
            PDRadioButton button = new PDRadioButton(acroForm);
            button.setPartialName("RadioButton" + options.get(i));

            PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
            fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[]{0, 0, 0}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));

            PDAnnotationWidget widget = button.getWidgets().get(0);
            widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(30, 800 - i * (21), 16, 16));
            widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

            acroForm.getFields().add(button);
            page.getAnnotations().add(widget);
        }
        contents.close();
        document.save(new FileOutputStream("RadioButtonTest.pdf"));
        document.close();
```

Comment: I created a non-perfect solution that I uploaded here: http://justpaste.it/CreateRadioButtons , assuming that answers here shouldn't be "in progress". There's some weirdness with the appearances that I wasn't able to solve. Were you able to create a perfectly working example with 1.8? If yes, please upload it somewhere.

Comment: @Tilman: I have tried to create a working example with 1.8 yet. Just been reading lots of documentation. I am just playing around with your example. Will report back anything i find.

Comment: @Tilman; sorry that was meant to be haven't tried.

Comment: @Tilman: I tweaked the font in your example and changed the border color to black, and was able to have a working set of radio buttons, but they look more like check-boxes (a square box with a tick) but behave like radio buttons (would expect a circle with a dot in the middle).
I don't know enough about pdf to know needs changing.

p.s. I have also posted the question to the pdfbox users mailing list to get to the correct audience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By looking at Tilman suggestions and by general fluke, I was able to come up with, what looks like, a solution to creating a radio button group.

note: I have been verifying my results by checking the pdf in Acrobat 11.

here is the code:

```
try {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

        document.addPage(page);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
        acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
        acroForm.setXFA(null);
        document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

        PDResources res = new PDResources();
        COSName fontName = res.add(font);
        acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
        acroForm.setDefaultAppearance('/' + fontName.getName() + " 10 Tf 0 g");

        PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        List<String> options = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
        PDRadioButton radioButton = new PDRadioButton(acroForm);
        radioButton.setPartialName("RadioButtonParent");
        radioButton.setExportValues(options);
        radioButton.getCOSObject().setName(COSName.DV, options.get(1));

        List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {

            PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
            fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[]{0, 0, 0}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));

            PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
            widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(30, 811 - i * (21), 16, 16));
            widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

            widgets.add(widget);
            page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

            // added by Tilman on 13.1.2017, without it Adobe does not set the values properly
            PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
            COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary();
            dict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Off"), new COSDictionary());
            dict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName(options.get(i)), new COSDictionary());
            PDAppearanceEntry appearanceEntry = new PDAppearanceEntry(dict);
            appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceEntry);
            widget.setAppearance(appearance);


            contents.beginText();
            contents.setFont(font, 10);
            contents.newLineAtOffset(56, 811 - i * (21) + 4);
            contents.showText(options.get(i));
            contents.endText();
        }
        radioButton.setWidgets(widgets);
        acroForm.getFields().add(radioButton);

        contents.close();
        try(FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test.pdf")) {
            document.save(output);
        }
        document.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The key seems to be setting the partial names of each radio button the the same value, but I can't say for sure.

Update 17.1.2019: I am the "Tilman" mentioned at the beginning, and have created a more flexible code for radio buttons and uploaded it into the [source code repository](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateRadioButtons.java?view=markup). It has the advantage that it creates the appearance streams similar to Adobe, so it is no longer needed to call `acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);`. The code works with PDFBox 2.0.13 and higher.

Comment: When I create a PDF with your code, open the PDF in Acrobat and save it again, it doesn't seem to recognize it as a PDRadioButton anymore when I iterate through form.getFields(). Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I doubled checked this morning using Acrobat 11.0.10 and it worked correctly, but also i am using PDF Box 2.0.0-RC3. just did a quick check with 2.0.4, and my application still continues to function as expected.

I use "pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().getFields()" with no problems.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. field instanceof PDRadioButton only works before I save it with Acrobat. Strange ^^

Comment: This has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631119/radiobutton-display-problems-with-pdfbox/41632982 , getFields() only gets the top of the tree. I edited some code in your answer for a different problem I discovered, when people clicked "c" it returned "Choice1" instead of "c".

Comment: There is a bug in the response, you should correct it, I don't want to mess too much in your response. Delete the  subRadioButtons stuff, and create the widget directly `PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget()`. What's also missing is the setParent and setPage stuff, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631119/ .

Comment: I am not sure there is, it works for my current situation for PDF Box 2.0.0-RC3. I don't currently have the time to look further into it.

You are welcome to test and update the response if you want.

My criteria at the time was PDF Box 2.0.0-RC3 and Acrobat Reader 11, things will be different for later versions of either.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Could you please state what version of PDF Box your code works with, in your update comment?

Comment: Sure, I've added it.