# Radiobutton display problems with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdfbox

I used the code from the answer from this question to create my radiobuttons:
[How to Create a Radio Button Group with PDFBox 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867139/how-to-create-a-radio-button-group-with-pdfbox-2-0)

After I created my PDF and tried to read the (programatically) selected value from it, this code worked fine:

```
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();

    for(PDField field: fields) {
        Object value = field.getValueAsString();
        String name = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
        if (field instanceof PDRadioButton) {
            // value is correct and field is instance of PDRadioButton works too
        }

    }
```

When I open the PDF in Acrobat Reader DC, make changes and save it again the code doesn't work anymore. There is no instance of PDRadioButton anymore and the value is always an empty string.
[image]

When I open the PDF in Acrobat Touch it doesn't even display properly.
[image]

(When I open the version that was previously edited by Acrobat Reader DC, Acrobat Touch can display it correctly)

Any suggestions what may be wrong with the code?

Here is a minimal example that behaves the same:

```
package test;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDColor;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDDeviceRGB;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotationWidget;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDRadioButton;


public class WriterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

            document.addPage(page);

            PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);
            acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);
            acroForm.setXFA(null);
            document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

            PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

            PDResources res = new PDResources();
            COSName fontName = res.add(font);
            acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
            acroForm.setDefaultAppearance('/' + fontName.getName() + " 10 Tf 0 g");

            PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

            List<String> options = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
            PDRadioButton radioButton = new PDRadioButton(acroForm);
            radioButton.setPartialName("RadioButtonParent");
            radioButton.setExportValues(options);
            radioButton.getCOSObject().setName(COSName.DV, options.get(1));

            List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
                PDRadioButton subRadioButtons = new PDRadioButton(acroForm);
                subRadioButtons.setPartialName("RadioButton");

                PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
                fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[] { 0, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));

                PDAnnotationWidget widget = subRadioButtons.getWidgets().get(0);
                widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(30, 811 - i * (21), 16, 16));
                widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);

                widgets.add(widget);
                page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

                contents.beginText();
                contents.setFont(font, 10);
                contents.newLineAtOffset(56, 811 - i * (21) + 4);
                contents.showText(options.get(i));
                contents.endText();
            }
            radioButton.setWidgets(widgets);
            acroForm.getFields().add(radioButton);

            contents.close();
            try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf")) {
                document.save(output);
            }
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't include the relevant code, pointing to the other answer isn't enough. I suggest you create code that creates a minimal PDF (e.g. with only 2 radio buttons) and then one could try to find out whether this is a programming error or a PDFBox bug or both.

Comment: well here it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code displays the top of the field tree. The javadoc of `getFields()` warns about this:

```
/**
 * This will return all of the documents root fields.
 * 
 * A field might have children that are fields (non-terminal field) or does not
 * have children which are fields (terminal fields).
 * 
 * The fields within an AcroForm are organized in a tree structure. The documents root fields 
 * might either be terminal fields, non-terminal fields or a mixture of both. Non-terminal fields
 * mark branches which contents can be retrieved using {@link PDNonTerminalField#getChildren()}.
 * 
 * @return A list of the documents root fields.
 * 
 */
public List<PDField> getFields()
```

To get all the fields (this includes non terminal fields), do this:

```
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
Iterator<PDField> fieldIterator = form.getFieldIterator();
while (fieldIterator.hasNext())
{
    PDField field = fieldIterator.next();
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Then your radio button appears.

However there are still another problem. The choice is returned as "a", "b" or "Choice1" instead of "c".

I was able to fix that by adding this code segment before adding the widget:

```
PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
COSDictionary dict = new COSDictionary();
dict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName("Off"), new COSDictionary());
dict.setItem(COSName.getPDFName(options.get(i)), new COSDictionary());
PDAppearanceEntry appearanceEntry = new PDAppearanceEntry(dict);
appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceEntry);
widget.setAppearance(appearance);
```

It adds empty appearances for "Off" and for the on-Option to each button.

Update 17.1.2017:

Here's source code to generate radio buttons with appearance streams:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage(PDRectangle.A4);

document.addPage(page);

PDAcroForm acroForm = new PDAcroForm(document);

// not needed, we have appearance streams
//acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);

acroForm.setXFA(null);
document.getDocumentCatalog().setAcroForm(acroForm);

PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;

PDResources res = new PDResources();
COSName fontName = res.add(font);
acroForm.setDefaultResources(res);
acroForm.setDefaultAppearance('/' + fontName.getName() + " 10 Tf 0 g");

PDPageContentStream contents = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

List<String> options = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
PDRadioButton radioButton = new PDRadioButton(acroForm);
radioButton.setPartialName("RadioButtonParent");
// removed per advice of Maruan Sahyoun, setValue didn't work anymore
//radioButton.setExportValues(options);
radioButton.getCOSObject().setName(COSName.DV, options.get(1));
radioButton.setFieldFlags(49152);
int on = 1;

List<PDAnnotationWidget> widgets = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++)
{
    PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary fieldAppearance = new PDAppearanceCharacteristicsDictionary(new COSDictionary());
    fieldAppearance.setBorderColour(new PDColor(new float[] { 0, 0, 0 }, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
    PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();
    widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(30, 811 - i * (21), 16, 16));
    widget.setAppearanceCharacteristics(fieldAppearance);
    widget.setAnnotationFlags(4);
    widget.setPage(page);
    widget.setParent(radioButton);

    String offNString = "0 G\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  7.5 0 m\n"
            + "  7.5 4.1423 4.1423 7.5 0 7.5 c\n"
            + "  -4.1423 7.5 -7.5 4.1423 -7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -7.5 -4.1423 -4.1423 -7.5 0 -7.5 c\n"
            + "  4.1423 -7.5 7.5 -4.1423 7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  s\n"
            + "Q";
    String onNString = "0 G\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  7.5 0 m\n"
            + "  7.5 4.1423 4.1423 7.5 0 7.5 c\n"
            + "  -4.1423 7.5 -7.5 4.1423 -7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -7.5 -4.1423 -4.1423 -7.5 0 -7.5 c\n"
            + "  4.1423 -7.5 7.5 -4.1423 7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  s\n"
            + "Q\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  3.5 0 m\n"
            + "  3.5 1.9331 1.9331 3.5 0 3.5 c\n"
            + "  -1.9331 3.5 -3.5 1.9331 -3.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -3.5 -1.9331 -1.9331 -3.5 0 -3.5 c\n"
            + "  1.9331 -3.5 3.5 -1.9331 3.5 0 c\n"
            + "  f\n"
            + "Q";
    String offDString = "0.749023 g\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  8 0 m\n"
            + "  8 4.4185 4.4185 8 0 8 c\n"
            + "  -4.4185 8 -8 4.4185 -8 0 c\n"
            + "  -8 -4.4185 -4.4185 -8 0 -8 c\n"
            + "  4.4185 -8 8 -4.4185 8 0 c\n"
            + "  f\n"
            + "Q\n"
            + "0 G\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  7.5 0 m\n"
            + "  7.5 4.1423 4.1423 7.5 0 7.5 c\n"
            + "  -4.1423 7.5 -7.5 4.1423 -7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -7.5 -4.1423 -4.1423 -7.5 0 -7.5 c\n"
            + "  4.1423 -7.5 7.5 -4.1423 7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  s\n"
            + "Q";
    String onDString = "0.749023 g\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  8 0 m\n"
            + "  8 4.4185 4.4185 8 0 8 c\n"
            + "  -4.4185 8 -8 4.4185 -8 0 c\n"
            + "  -8 -4.4185 -4.4185 -8 0 -8 c\n"
            + "  4.4185 -8 8 -4.4185 8 0 c\n"
            + "  f\n"
            + "Q\n"
            + "0 G\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  7.5 0 m\n"
            + "  7.5 4.1423 4.1423 7.5 0 7.5 c\n"
            + "  -4.1423 7.5 -7.5 4.1423 -7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -7.5 -4.1423 -4.1423 -7.5 0 -7.5 c\n"
            + "  4.1423 -7.5 7.5 -4.1423 7.5 0 c\n"
            + "  s\n"
            + "Q\n"
            + "0 g\n"
            + "q\n"
            + "  1 0 0 1 8 8 cm\n"
            + "  3.5 0 m\n"
            + "  3.5 1.9331 1.9331 3.5 0 3.5 c\n"
            + "  -1.9331 3.5 -3.5 1.9331 -3.5 0 c\n"
            + "  -3.5 -1.9331 -1.9331 -3.5 0 -3.5 c\n"
            + "  1.9331 -3.5 3.5 -1.9331 3.5 0 c\n"
            + "  f\n"
            + "Q";
    COSDictionary apNDict = new COSDictionary();
    COSStream offNStream = new COSStream();
    offNStream.setItem(COSName.BBOX, new PDRectangle(16, 16));
    offNStream.setItem(COSName.FORMTYPE, COSInteger.ONE);
    offNStream.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.XOBJECT);
    offNStream.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.FORM);
    OutputStream os = offNStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
    os.write(offNString.getBytes());
    os.close();
    apNDict.setItem(COSName.Off, offNStream);

    COSStream onNStream = new COSStream();
    onNStream.setItem(COSName.BBOX, new PDRectangle(16, 16));
    onNStream.setItem(COSName.FORMTYPE, COSInteger.ONE);
    onNStream.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.XOBJECT);
    onNStream.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.FORM);
    os = onNStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
    os.write(onNString.getBytes());
    os.close();
    apNDict.setItem(options.get(i), onNStream);

    COSDictionary apDDict = new COSDictionary();
    COSStream offDStream = new COSStream();
    offDStream.setItem(COSName.BBOX, new PDRectangle(16, 16));
    offDStream.setItem(COSName.FORMTYPE, COSInteger.ONE);
    offDStream.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.XOBJECT);
    offDStream.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.FORM);
    os = offDStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
    os.write(offDString.getBytes());
    os.close();
    apDDict.setItem(COSName.Off, offDStream);

    COSStream onDStream = new COSStream();
    onDStream.setItem(COSName.BBOX, new PDRectangle(16, 16));
    onDStream.setItem(COSName.FORMTYPE, COSInteger.ONE);
    onDStream.setItem(COSName.TYPE, COSName.XOBJECT);
    onDStream.setItem(COSName.SUBTYPE, COSName.FORM);
    os = onDStream.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
    os.write(onDString.getBytes());
    os.close();
    apDDict.setItem(options.get(i), onDStream);

    PDAppearanceDictionary appearance = new PDAppearanceDictionary();
    PDAppearanceEntry appearanceNEntry = new PDAppearanceEntry(apNDict);
    appearance.setNormalAppearance(appearanceNEntry);
    PDAppearanceEntry appearanceDEntry = new PDAppearanceEntry(apDDict);
    appearance.setDownAppearance(appearanceDEntry);

    widget.setAppearance(appearance);

    widget.setAppearanceState(i == on ? options.get(i) : "Off");

    widgets.add(widget);
    page.getAnnotations().add(widget);

    contents.beginText();
    contents.setFont(font, 10);
    contents.newLineAtOffset(56, 811 - i * (21) + 4);
    contents.showText(options.get(i));
    contents.endText();
}
radioButton.setWidgets(widgets);
acroForm.getFields().add(radioButton);

contents.close();
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"))
{
    document.save(output);
}
document.close();
```

If you want Adobe to generate the appearance streams (that's the "gibberish" in the code), call `setNeedAppearances(true)` and remove the line `widget.setAppearance(appearance);`. If you open the file with Adobe and save it, the appearance streams will be generated, and that is where I got these from. You can see these with PDFDebugger if you look at the annotations, then AP and go down from there.

That's also the strategy to use if you want to know the appearance stream content for bigger buttons.

Some time in the future PDFBox will generate the appearance streams for buttons. There is some math involved, see [here](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/) or in the trunk source code in PDCircleAppearanceHandler.

Comment: Did you try to take a look at the PDF in Acrobat Reader and Acrobat Touch? Because I can get the value somehow with the COSObject but the bigger problem is the wrong rendering in Acrobat Touch

Comment: PDFBox doesn't construct the appearances. Adobe Reader DC does this, and maybe Adobe Touch doesn't. I don't have access to Adobe touch (I don't have windows 8 or higher). I looked at the file on my android phone and there the original file shows squares instead of circles, and the squares go white when touching them.

Comment: It might be possible to set the missing appearance streams with PDFBox, by just copying the content stream (look at it with PDFDebugger) and the BBox. To see what I mean, look at `Root/Pages/Kids/[0]/Annots/[0]/AP/N/a` with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Please try the code I posted here: https://justpaste.it/12dyc this creates appearance streams. Tell me if it works on Adobe touch.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll try it on monday when I have to work :)

Comment: It still looks broken.

Comment: Could you create a radiobutton group from a PDNonTerminalField? Because that's what I get after I save the PDF with Acrobat and try to read it programatically (instead of PDRadioButton)

Comment: You got a PDNonTerminalField because adobe inserts an extra level, I'm not persuaded that this is important but I will look at the PDF specification. See the first part of my response on how to get all, not just the non terminal field. Re "It still looks broken" - could you test by removing the line `acroForm.setNeedAppearances(true);` ?

Comment: When I remove the line it doesn't work anywhere anymore. Regarding the extra level: after Acrobat Reader "added" the extra level, every PDF Reader could handle the radiobuttons. Maybe it will work then?

Comment: Try this: remove the lines with "subRadioButtons". Instead, insert a line `PDAnnotationWidget widget = new PDAnnotationWidget();` and `widget.setPage(page);`.

Comment: Now there are empty squares with all the options (not just the first as above) but they are not clickable.

Comment: It works for me on my Android mobile if I do both the part about removing "subRadioButtons" and removing the "setNeedAppearances" lines. I.e. the round buttons appear, and selected at the correct button.

Comment: On my android phone it doesn't work. I have the google PDF Viewer and the Polaris Office Viewer. Could you paste your whole code in the answer? Maybe I overlooked something

Comment: I used Adobe Reader on the phone. The other two display correctly but don't allow setting. I'll update my external answer tonight (in about 5 hours).

Comment: I've updated the code at https://jpst.it/RB0D . It works fine on my Android phone with the Adobe Reader app, I'm even able to change the buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and thanks for helping me! I'd invite you to a beer if you weren't this far away :)

Comment: Did the external code work for you this time? Because if yes then I'll add it to the resopnse.

Comment: The code you posted works. I just have a little trouble resizing the radiobutton.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr 
can you please share the function name for "radio button is checked by default"

Comment: `widget.setAppearanceState` is the part where the button is checked.