# Pdfbox2.0 3 add radio button with label on same row/line

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to add three radio buttons with label in a line on a pdf using pdfbox version2.0.4

I am following this code from this post. I tried changing the x and y coordinates and also tried reusing the same PDRectangle object rather than creating a new every time.
[How to Create a Radio Button Group with PDFBox 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867139/how-to-create-a-radio-button-group-with-pdfbox-2-0)

```
widget.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(30, PDRectangle.A4.getHeight() - 40 - i * 35, 30, 30));
```

I expect to see 3 radio button with label on the same line like 
radioBtn Yes  radioBtn No  radioBtn Don't Know

Comment: try to add more details in your question. I have read it twice and understood nothing. Add your code below, with your own implementation, and say us what problem you have.

Comment: There is an example in the source code download, CreateRadioButtons.java. That one aligns on a vertical line, so you'd just have to change that. Your question does not explain what didn't work. And you are using an outdated pdfbox version, the current is 2.0.15. Older versions may have security risks, so use these only if you work at Equifax or Boeing.

Comment: Title: "pdfbox2.0 3 add radio button with label on same row/line" Body: "need to add three radio buttons with label in a line on a pdf using pdfbox version2.0.4" - Which version is it, 2.0.3 or 2.0.4? (But whichever it is, you should update as recommended by @TilmanHausherr)

Comment: Please press the checkmark on the answer if it solves your problem, of comment if you need more support.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but a very quick glance at the example, have you tried
incrementing the x-position of each PDRectangle in the loop where the radiobutton options are added? (Instead of varying the y-position as in the original example)
I would start by trying to replace

```
new PDRectangle(30, PDRectangle.A4.getHeight() - 40 - i * 35, 30, 30)
```

with something like

```
new PDRectangle(30 + i * 35, PDRectangle.A4.getHeight() - 40, 30, 30)
```

But then again - I may have completely misunderstood your question. If so; I apologize.